# suppressEmails:true not working for compositeTemplates envelope creation

Tags: docusignapi

When using REST to create a standard envelope with the Docusign API, I can add a property to the "signer" recipient of "suppressEmails": "true", which works to prevent any emails from being sent from Docusign, and allows me to handle the entire signature request via an embed.

However, I have refactored that basic envelope creation request to use the compositeTemplates workflow. I have this functional with the embed URL being generated correctly, however, the suppressEmails flag no longer works to prevent Docusign from sending the user an email notification.

Is there something I am missing?  Here is an example of the envelope request:

```
{
   "compositeTemplates":[
      {
         "compositeTemplateId":"1",
         "document":{
            "documentId":"1",
            "name":"<redacted>",
            "fileExtension":"pdf",
            "documentBase64":"<redacted>",
            "signerMustAcknowledge":"accept"
         },
         "inlineTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":"1",
               "recipients":{
                  "signers":[
                     {
                        "recipientId":"1",
                        "routingOrder":"1",
                        "clientUserId":"<redacted>",
                        "name":"<redacted>",
                        "email":"<redacted>",
                        "roleName":"signer",
                        "suppressEmails":"true"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "serverTemplates":null
      },
      {
         "compositeTemplateId":"2",
         "inlineTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":"2",
               "recipients":{
                  "signers":[
                     {
                        "recipientId":"1",
                        "routingOrder":"1",
                        "clientUserId":"<redacted>",
                        "name":"<redacted>",
                        "email":"<redacted>",
                        "roleName":"signer",
                        "suppressEmails":"true"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "serverTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":"2",
               "templateId":"<guid>"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "emailSubject":"Please sign",
   "status":"sent"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By default, captive recipients (for embedded signing) do not get email notifications of any sort.  There is an option to receive the "envelope complete" notification email, and this is set at the account level by an admin.

The signer::supressEmails element, according to the documentation, is for remote recipients and is only applicable to DocuSign Users.  This element suppresses the normal email notifications and forces them to access the envelope via their DocuSign Inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Did a bit of poking around on your behalf. The envelope definition below works like a charm for me. It should enable you to create a composite template from a document and server template, both recipients with suppressed emails.

Let me know if you have any more questions

```
{
        "emailSubject": "subject line goes here",
        "status": "sent",
        "compositeTemplates": [{
             "compositeTemplateId":"1",
             "document":{
                "documentId":"1",
                "name":"doc1",
                "fileExtension":"pdf",
                "documentBase64":"<insert your doc>",
                "signerMustAcknowledge":"accept"
             },
            "inlineTemplates": [{
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [{
                        "email": "< signer email >",
                        "name": "John Doe",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "clientUserId": "12345",
                        "suppressEmails": true,
                        "roleName": "Buyer"
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }, {
            "serverTemplates": [{
                "sequence": "2",
                "templateId": "< enter the template id>"
            }],
            "inlineTemplates": [{
                "sequence": "2",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [{
                        "email": "< 2nd signer email >",
                        "name": "Sally Doe",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "clientUserId": "6789",
                        "suppressEmails": true,
                        "roleName": "Seller"
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
```