# Disable completion email at envelope level

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign REST API to create and send an envelope from a template. When the document is completed, we need to either suppress the completion email to signers entirely or exclude the attachment from the email. The problem is, we do not want to do this at the account level, but at the envelope level (we only need this for one particular template). As far as I can tell, the options for this cannot be changed at the envelope or even the user level, but are global to every user in our account.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you can do the reverse, disable it for the account and then for these envelopes you want it - you can add it. I'm not sure it's possible to suppress it for a specific envelope or template....

Comment: I did find in the API documentation a property called "suppressEmails" for the "signer" object definition. I can't seem to figure out if I can set this when defining the envelope recipients.
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/get#signer

Comment: oh, you may want to look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998219/suppressemailstrue-not-working-for-compositetemplates-envelope-creation

Comment: In that example he is adding the suppressEmails property to an inlineTemplate. Strangely, I can't seem to add that property to my recipients on an existing template. If I run the following update on a template, the property is not added when I retrieve the template afterwards.

`{
 "recipients" : 
 {
  "signers" : 
  [
   {
    "recipientId" : "1",
    "suppressEmails" : true
   },
   {
    "recipientId" : "2",
    "suppressEmails" : true
   },
   {
    "recipientId" : "3",
    "suppressEmails" : false
   }
  ]
 }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to also add a clientUserID to each recipient when creating the envelopes. If you do not specify a clientUserID, your recipients will receive the email, despite the "suppressEmails" property being set to true. If you add the CUID, then it will honor the suppress emails. This feature is recommended for embedded, or captive, signers.

If your end-users do not have a DocuSign account, they will have no way of accessing the envelope since the RecipientView url is not delivered via email.

Here is a sample request that creates a new envelope from a template with a single recipient ...

```
{
    "templateId": "62b565ce-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-a849fe664e88",
    "templateRoles": [{
          "roleName": "{sample_role}",
          "name": "{sample_email}",
          "email": "{sample_email}",
          "clientUserId": "1",
          "suppressEmails": true
      }],
      "status": "sent"
}
```

For more information on these variants, check out a [great blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-why-use-composite-templates/) on the three main variants of envelope creation

Comment: Thank you! That gets me mostly there- I can now suppress all emails to specific recipients in an envelope.

Now I just need to figure out if I can manually send the initial signing email while retaining the suppressEmail property. I was hoping that I could send the envelope, then update it afterwards with the suppressEmails property, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Just a note- If I update the signers after the initial envelope creation with a clientUserId and suppressEmails, it seems to create new signers with new userIds, which renders the initial recipient emails invalid. I feel like I'm on the right track, but it may just not be possible to modify suppressEmails after the envelope is sent.

Comment: I do believe you are correct. You can only suppress all emails at the envelope creation step using that property. I've filed an internal ticket to investigate this behavior and (at the very least) update our documentation to help clarify this property (DEVDOCS-2419)

Comment: Thank you, in the meantime I will look into an embedded signing solution where I can control the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `suppressEmails` is only available for the v2.1 version of the eSignature API.

Also, in your question, you say "suppress the completion email". `suppressEmails` will stop all emails from going out to a signer.

If you want to suppress the attachment for just one signer, try using document visibility for the attachment.